# how to know when an outgoing call is picked?

Tags: android

How can i know that.. there seems to be no solution?? y is it soo?

```
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch(state) {
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    Log.d("Tony","Outgoing Call finished");
                    // Call Finished -> stop counter and store it.
                    callStop=new Date().getTime();
                    context.stopService(new Intent(context,ListenerContainer.class));

                break;
            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    Log.d("Tony","Outgoing Call Starting");
                    // Call Started -> start counter.
                    // This is not precise, because it starts when calling,
                    // we can correct it later reading from call log
                    callStart=new Date().getTime();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Here we have only 2 states ?? any other solution?
As soon as we start the call OFFHOOK is started and it remains until the call is ended.. there is no way to differentiate when its ringing or picked.. My project need to know when the call is picked..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no public API to the same.  Also you can try printing the information EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK to see if it contains any information when the call is connected.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of detect if an outgoing call is answered. You can identify when an incoming call is ringing and when it is answered but no the same with outgoing calls, because when you dial the number the OFFHOOK state is triggered.